# rqt based UI and different screen resolutions

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created a UI using rqt, and store the UI as a perspective. My problem is that individual components in the UI don't render at the same location if a different screen resolution is used. The UI was created in 1920 x 1080, and is being viewed on a different machine with 2560 x 1440. Any thoughts to keep the layout completely fixed will be appreciated. Since a number of people are using the UI, it's hard to control the resolution at which it will be viewed.

I'm using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04, should it matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267239/rqt-based-ui-and-different-screen-resolutions/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want the perspective to be "pixel-perfect" you might want to use a not maximized window. That should at least work exactly the on all resolutions which are at least of the desired size.

In general I think it would be more flexible to allow dynamic scaling of all your layout.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2017-07-24**:
The main window is not maximized at launch. It just spawns with a different size at different resolutions, which means the internal plugins get pushed around at resolutions other than the one it was designed for and the interface doesn't look nice.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-07-24**:
The resolution of the window should be saved / restored to / from the perspective file. It shouldn't change as long as the desired resolution fits onto the screen. Maybe you can describe a minimal reproducible example others can try to confirm that there is a problem.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2017-07-24**:
Thanks for the quick response @Dirk Thomas.  I've added an issue/steps to reproduce on this github thread: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt/issues/123